# AWS Lambda Boto3 python - filter expression on dynamodb table throw error "errorMessage": "name 'Attr' is not defined",

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using a filter on dynamodb table. it throws error the following error.
Boto3 documentation shows response = table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('myattribute').eq('myvalue')

I did same thing. I want items in this table where the agentRole = Receiver

```
  Response
  {
        "errorMessage": "name 'Attr' is not defined",
        "errorType": "NameError",
        "requestId": "1b2fbee6-5fa2-4951-8689-3d1bfec76e5c",
         "stackTrace": [
              "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 21, in lambda_handler\n    
          response = tableresource.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('agentRole').eq('Receiver'))\n"
       ]
   }
```

This is the code:

```
   import json
   import os
   import boto3
   from pprint import pprint

    #Find records that has agentRole as 'Receiver'

    tableName = os.environ.get('TABLE')
    fieldName = os.environ.get('FIELD')
    keytofind = os.environ.get('FILTER')
    fieldname = "agentRole"
    dbclient = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
   
         tableresource = dbclient.Table(tableName)
         count = tableresource.item_count
         response = tableresource.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('agentRole').eq('Receiver'))
```

Comment: you need to import Attr from somewhere first presumably ... see the docs https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan   (specifically scroll down to the `Examples` section)

Comment: @Joran, There is no "import" in the docs for "scan" in version 1.28.30. It looks like this version of the documentation endorses using variable/values defined ExpressionAttributeValues along literal field names in the FilterExpression.

Answer (score 5):

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr
```

Comment: Thank You. But how do I know this module to import? Is there a documenation that says to import specific modules?

Comment: @Jason https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Attr